# dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename `/usr/lib/gio/modules' and package `libglib2.0-0'

Tags: sed, linux-mint, dpkg

[Reposted from askubuntu.com]

I can't install any software. I think this dates from an unexpected power loss a few days ago.

When I try `sudo apt-get install gparted` I see

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython2.7-minimal mime-support python2.7-minimal
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  busybox-initramfs cpio dmsetup fontconfig fontconfig-config
  fonts-dejavu-core initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initscripts
  klibc-utils kmod libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatkmm-1.6-1 libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo2 libcairomm-1.0-1
  libcgmanager0 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdbus-1-3 libdevmapper1.02.1 libexpat1
  libffi6 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgcrypt11 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libglib2.0-0 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgnutls26
  libgpg-error0 libgraphite2-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libharfbuzz0b libjasper1 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8
  libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libklibc libkmod2 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
  libncursesw5 libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libp11-kit0 libpango-1.0-0
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libparted0debian1
  libpixman-1-0 libpng12-0 libprocps3 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libtasn1-6
  libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libudev1 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6
  libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1
  libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxml2 libxrandr2
  libxrender1 module-init-tools procps shared-mime-info ucf udev
Suggested packages:
  libarchive1 xfsprogs reiserfsprogs reiser4progs jfsutils ntfs-3g dosfstools
  yelp kpartx dmraid gpart bash-completion cups-common rng-tools gnutls-bin
  krb5-doc krb5-user librsvg2-common gvfs libjasper-runtime ttf-baekmuk
  ttf-arphic-gbsn00lp ttf-arphic-bsmi00lp ttf-arphic-gkai00mp
  ttf-arphic-bkai00mp parted nparted libparted0-dev libparted0-i18n
Recommended packages:
  psmisc dbus libglib2.0-data hicolor-icon-theme libgtk2.0-bin krb5-locales
  libgpm2 xml-core
The following NEW packages will be installed
  busybox-initramfs cpio dmsetup fontconfig fontconfig-config
  fonts-dejavu-core gparted initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initscripts
  klibc-utils kmod libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatkmm-1.6-1 libavahi-client3
  libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 libcairo2 libcairomm-1.0-1
  libcgmanager0 libcups2 libdatrie1 libdbus-1-3 libdevmapper1.02.1 libexpat1
  libffi6 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgcrypt11 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libglib2.0-0 libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libgnutls26
  libgpg-error0 libgraphite2-3 libgssapi-krb5-2 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libharfbuzz0b libjasper1 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8
  libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1 libklibc libkmod2 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
  libncursesw5 libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libp11-kit0 libpango-1.0-0
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libparted0debian1
  libpixman-1-0 libpng12-0 libprocps3 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a libtasn1-6
  libthai-data libthai0 libtiff5 libudev1 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6
  libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1
  libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxml2 libxrandr2
  libxrender1 module-init-tools procps shared-mime-info ucf udev
0 to upgrade, 92 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/14.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 59.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extract templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename `/usr/lib/gio/modules' and package `libglib2.0-0'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

This is after trying several fixes, I have eliminated other errors which were occuring previously but I did not record them.

I have tried the procedure in https://askubuntu.com/questions/134842/dpkg-error-duplicate-file-trigger-interest-for-filename-usr-lib-gio-modules but I don't know how to use `sed` (nor, really, what it is).  The command suggested there is

```
sed -n -e"s,/,\\\\\\\\/,g; s/:$(dpkg --print-architecture)$//p " \
      /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File \
| while read line; do
     sudo sed -i -e"/^$line$/d" /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File
done
```

When I paste that block into the terminal, or run it as a separate script, I get no feedback; the terminal sends me straight back to the prompt instantly, and when I try again to install gparted, I get exactly the same messages as mentioned.

I have tried to look directly at `/usr/lib/gio/modules` but I can't see `/usr/lib/gio`; it appears to not exist!

I'm running `Linux Mint 17.2 64-bit`, `uname -r` gives `3.16.0-38-generic`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a well-known problem, probably a `dpkg` or some installscript bug.

`/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` contain a list of files and triggers (in the installscript) to use with.

This file should be a simple text file, without any duplicated entries. Edit it with a text editor, and check. If there are duplicates, fix them (make a backup from this before that).

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I used Libreoffice Calc (yeah I know) to parse `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` and found four duplicates.  Deleted those, ran
`apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`, and installed `gparted`.  Didn't even need to reboot (or close Kerbal Space Program, for that matter).