# Duplicate file trigger interest doesn't have duplicates

Tags: linux, apt, dpkg

Before it gets flagged as duplicate I am aware of [dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename `/usr/lib/gio/modules' and package `libglib2.0-0'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229225/86440).

I checked the solution in the answer to the aforementioned question and my `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` contained 0 duplicate entries.

I am running Pop_OS! and the following is the output when I try to run `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libapparmor1 libargon2-1 libcryptsetup12 libdevmapper1.02.1 libexpat1
  libip4tc2 libjson-c5 libkmod2 libmpdec3 libpython3-stdlib
  libpython3.9-minimal libpython3.9-stdlib libreadline8 libsqlite3-0
  media-types python3 python3-minimal python3.9 python3.9-minimal
  readline-common systemd systemd-timesyncd tzdata
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
22 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for filename '/usr/lib/gio/modules'
 and package 'libglib2.0-0:i386'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Similliarly to the aformentioned question the `/usr/lib/gio` directory didn't exist on my machine.

However the output of `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` is as follows

```
/etc/dbus-1/system.d dbus/noawait
/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d dbus/noawait
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services dbus/noawait
/usr/lib/mime/packages mailcap/noawait
/usr/share/applications mailcap/noawait
/etc/rsyslog.d rsyslog/noawait
/usr/share/mime/packages shared-mime-info/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0/noawait
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0/noawait
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0
/usr/share/icons/hicolor hicolor-icon-theme/noawait
/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0/noawait
/usr/share/fonts fontconfig/noawait
/usr/share/ghostscript/fonts fontconfig/noawait
/usr/share/texmf/fonts fontconfig/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules libgtk-3-0/noawait
/usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules libgtk-3-0/noawait
/var/lib/dictionaries-common/hunspell dictionaries-common/noawait
/usr/share/applications desktop-file-utils/noawait
/usr/share/applications gnome-menus/noawait
/usr/share/icons/gnome gnome-icon-theme/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules libgtk2.0-0/noawait
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules libgtk2.0-0/noawait
/usr/man man-db/noawait
/usr/share/man man-db/noawait
/usr/local/man man-db/noawait
/usr/local/share/man man-db/noawait
/usr/X11R6/man man-db/noawait
/opt/man man-db/noawait
/usr/share/cups/ppd-updaters cups/noawait
/etc/sgml sgml-base
/usr/share/sgml sgml-base
/usr/share/xml sgml-base
/usr/share/app-info/icons appstream/noawait
/usr/share/app-info/yaml appstream/noawait
/usr/share/app-info/xml appstream/noawait
/usr/share/dict cracklib-runtime/noawait
/usr/dict cracklib-runtime/noawait
/usr/local/share/dict cracklib-runtime/noawait
/usr/local/dict cracklib-runtime/noawait
/usr/lib/rygel-2.6 rygel/noawait
/usr/share/info install-info/noawait
/etc/lsb-release plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text/noawait
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:i386/noawait
/usr/lib/gio/modules libglib2.0-0:i386/noawait
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas libglib2.0-0:i386
/usr/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:i386/noawait
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:i386/noawait
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib libwine-development/noawait
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib libwine-development/noawait
/usr/bin/wine64-stable wine/noawait
/usr/bin/winegcc-stable wine/noawait
/usr/share/applications bamfdaemon/noawait
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins libvlc-bin/noawait
/lib/udev/hwdb.d udev/noawait
/etc/ufw/applications.d ufw/noawait
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions libreoffice-common/noawait
/usr/lib/libreoffice libreoffice-common/noawait
/usr/share/texmf tex-common/noawait
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist tex-common/noawait
/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc tex-common/noawait
/usr/lib/systemd/catalog systemd/noawait
```

The contents of the directory is as follows

```
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/aspell-autobuildhash
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/gmenucache
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/ispell-autobuildhash
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/ldconfig
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/linux-update-5.11.0-7633-generic
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/linux-update-5.13.0-7614-generic
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/linux-update-5.13.0-7620-generic
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/linux-update-5.15.5-76051505-generic
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Lock
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/resolvconf-enable-updates
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/rygel-restart
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/texmf-format
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/texmf-hyphen
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/texmf-map
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/update-ca-certificates
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/update-ca-certificates-fresh
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/update-default-ispell
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/update-default-wordlist
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/update-initramfs
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/update-sgmlcatalog
/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/wine
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `grep /usr/lib/gio/modules /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/*`?